# Working with DLL in a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, dll, id3lib

I'm planning to use [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) in my application. I'm looking for a way to use the library as a DLL. I've noticed that they released the library in various form: one of which is [windows binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3lib/files/windows%20binaries/3.8.3/). My target platform in Windows, and I'll use Qt 4.8. After I extract the files in windows binary, I found the following files in Release folder:

- id3lib.dll
- id3lib.exp
- id3lib.lib

I know how to use a DLL in Qt given the DLL, one or more header files where function prototypes resides, and with or without the *.lib file. This package doesn't come with a header file.

How am I supposed to use this package without any header file? What's the purpose of the *.lib and *.exp files here? As far as I know *.lib files are used for static linking with functions which I don't want in my program.

Comment: Your question is Windows specific and should be tagged as such.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: yep, sorry i forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual course is to use a header file #included in the C++ file, the .lib file to link to and the .dll is required at run time.

The header file should/may be in another package as the same header is probably used for different kinds of linking strategies.

At worst you should be able to use a tool such as depends.exe to view the exported symbols and create your own h file to match - but it would be better to find a .h file issued with the release.

Answer (score 2):

You've just missed the header. It is available under the include subfolder (see [here](http://id3lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/id3lib/id3lib-stable/include/)), also the .lib file is still needed for linking, even if you'll be using the DLL.

Comment: I've the complete source code of id3lib. the windows binary section doesn't come with any header file. how do i know which header file should i use?

Comment: @Donotalo: follow the link in Robert's answer.  It takes you straight to id3.h.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: id3.h is not the file to include. it is tag.h described here: http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/api/index.html. however, i tried both of them but still couldn't resolve some unreferenced link.

Comment: @Donotalo: are you getting an error from the compiler or from the linker?  What functions/symbols are undefined?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: that's another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786022/undefined-reference-linker-error-while-using-id3lib-library-in-a-c-application