# Undefined reference linker error while using id3lib library in a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, id3lib

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I'm using Qt 4.8 to write a program that will use id3lib. I've downloaded the [windows binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3lib/files/windows%20binaries/). Here is part of the *.pro file that shows how id3lib library is used:

```
HEADERS  += MainWindow.h \
    id3lib/id3/sized_types.h \
    id3lib/id3/globals.h \
    id3lib/id3/tag.h \
    id3lib/id3/utils.h \
    id3lib/id3/id3lib_frame.h \
    id3lib/id3/field.h \
    id3lib/id3/id3lib_strings.h \
    id3lib/id3/id3lib_streams.h

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/id3lib/ -lid3lib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/id3lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/id3lib
```

As you can guess, the library files (id3lib.dll and id3lib.lib) are in `id3lib` directory and all required headers are in `id3lib/id3` directory.

In the globals.h, I defined the follwing:

```
#define ID3LIB_LINKOPTION LINKOPTION_CREATE_DYNAMIC
```

And modified the following section in the same file:

```
#    if (ID3LIB_LINKOPTION == LINKOPTION_CREATE_DYNAMIC)
       //used for creating a dynamic dll
#      define ID3_C_EXPORT extern _declspec(dllexport)
#      define ID3_CPP_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#      define CCONV __stdcall // Added for VB & Delphi Compatibility - By FrogPrince Advised By Lothar
#    endif
```

as follows:

```
#    if (ID3LIB_LINKOPTION == LINKOPTION_CREATE_DYNAMIC)
       //used for creating a dynamic dll
#      define ID3_C_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#      define ID3_CPP_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#      define CCONV __stdcall // Added for VB & Delphi Compatibility - By FrogPrince Advised By Lothar
#    endif
```

so that it works with Qt.

Next, I've included `id3/tag.h` and written the following code:

```
ID3_Tag tag("test.wma");
qDebug() << tag.size();
```

After compilation, I got the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7ID3_TagC1EPKc'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK7ID3_Tag4SizeEv'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7ID3_TagD1Ev'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7ID3_TagD1Ev'
(several few, same format: `_imp___xxxxx_Tagxxxx')
```

I know what causes undefined reference, but in my case, why the linker couldn't find the implementation? Is it now there in the id3lib.dll? Does anyone know if there is any workaround?

Comment: @Lol4t0: yes. I'm using Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies not in tool chains, but ABI.

It *does* exist standard *plain C* ABI, so you can link against both `lib` and `a` by `MinGw`, if they contain only *plain C* symbols.

But it is not true in you case (since such define as `ID3_CPP_EXPORT` exist).

You should try to make library by youserlf. 
To begin with, install `msys`, open msys shell, go to project folder and try

```
./configure && make
```

Comment: in your answer you mentioned ABI. what's ABI?

Comment: @Donotalo, In general it a sort of agreement bellow the standard. You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492180/c-abi-issues-list) and [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) what it describes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using Visual Studio that support .lib files to link your project to the right DLL you need id3lib.a (or something similar). GNU tool chain is different from MS one so you need the right static link files. My advice is to compile the library on your own on your compiler, since it is open source it's worth doing it.